# Logging filename, line number in logs. Do I need to pass the StackFrame?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, stack-frame

Currently, I pass the StackFrame to grab the current file/line number:

```
Log.Message(new StackFrame(0, true), "FAILED to start cooling.");
```

Where in the Log class is:

```
public void Message(StackFrame Callstack, string message)
{
    string logMessage = string.Format("{0} {1}:{2} {3} \t{4}", DateTime.Now.ToString(), Callstack.GetFileName(), Callstack.GetFileLineNumber(), Callstack.GetMethod(), message);

    //Write to console
    Console.WriteLine(logMessage);

    //write to file
}
```

Do I need to pass the StackFrame each time to the Log.Message() method? Can this be done in the method it self without passing it? Is there a simpler method?

Thanks.

Comment: How did you write in the file ?

Comment: Writing to a file is unrelated to the question. You could google how to write a String to a file and there will be lots of matches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
public void Message(string message) {
    StackFrame callstack = new StackFrame(1, true);
    // ...
}
```

The `1` skips the Message method part of the callstack and gets it caller.

Answer (score 0):

You can. The first constructor parameter of `StackFrame` defines the number of frames to skip. So when creating the object instance within `Message()` just pass `1` and it will show the calling frame (where you used the call to `Message()`).